# PostgreSQL date trigger syntax error

Tags: postgresql, date, triggers, syntax-error

I'm a newbie at SQL and I have no idea what I am doing wrong trying to execute that code in PostgreSQL (I added numbers here to mark the lines):

```
create function annouc_dates()
returns trigger as '
begin
    if new.creation_date is NULL then
        new.creation_date := select current_timestamp;
    end if;
    if new.removal_date is NULL then
        new.removal_date := select new.creation_date + interval '2 week';
    end if;
    return new;
end';
```

I get a message:
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "2"
LINE 8: ...emoval_date := new.creation_date + interval '2 week';

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue concerns nested quoting. Use Postgres dollar-quoting as described in [4.1.2.4. Dollar-quoted String Constants.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html)

```
create function annouc_dates()
returns trigger language plpgsql as $$
begin
    if new.creation_date is NULL then
        new.creation_date := current_timestamp;
    end if;
    if new.removal_date is NULL then
        new.removal_date := new.creation_date + interval '2 week';
    end if;
    return new;
end
$$;
```

Comment: I did as you adviced me, but I got error that the language is not specified, so I added clause 'language plpgsql' and then I got error that still something is wrong with line 5.                                    
'ERROR:  syntax error at or near "select"
LINE 5:         new.creation_date := select current_timestamp;'

Comment: `new.creation_date := select current_timestamp;` can be simplified to `new.creation_date := current_timestamp;` and the same for the assignment of `new.removal_date`

Comment: I focused on the error message and missed other blunders, sorry. See the updated answer.